# Winding Number Problem

Tags: complex-analysis, winding-number

Suppose $a \in \mathbb{C}$ and $r>0$. Let $D(a,r)$ be a disk. Show that 
$Win(\partial D(a,r),z)= 1$ when $|z-a|<r$ and $Win(\partial D(a,r),z)= 0$ when $|z-a|>r$

I am not sure where to even start with this problem. I know it is talking about a point inside the disk and the winding number is 1 and a point outside the disk and the winding number is 0, but I am not sure where to put a piecewise smooth curve $\gamma(t)$.

Comment: The piecewise smooth curve in question is the circle $\partial D(a,r)$, appropriately parameterized.

Comment: Then $\gamma(t) = a + re^{it}$ would be the parameterized smooth curve?Ok, so let a point $z_{0}$ be inside the interior of the disk, so $z_{0}$ is in the piecewise smooth curve. Then consider a point $z_{1}$ outside the piecewise smooth curve. Then I can proceed from here, but is this a correct start?

Comment: That's correct. But, of course, your parameterization needs a domain.

Comment: Of course, since we are on the circle then $t \in [0, 2\pi]$

Comment: Is $Win(set,c)$ supposed to be something well known and recognized?